# ClassNotFoundException when deploying GWT-RPC-Applicaton to OpenShift

Tags: java, maven, gwt, rpc, openshift

I deployed my webapp (written with GWT and using Remote Procedure Calls (RPC)) to `OpenShift`.
If I access my application a RPC is called. I checked the log-files and the following exception is the result:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.RemoteService
```

Does anyone know, how to fix that? I used Maven to build my application (`mvn clean install`)

Comment: Open the .war file and check if the dependency is there.

Comment: Where should it be? How would these dependencies look like?

Comment: Read [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.RemoteService](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20482165/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-google-gwt-user-client-rpc-remoteservice)

Comment: Please share `pom.xml`.

Comment: Open as if it was a zip file (Open With > 7-Zip or whatever, on Windows). You will be able to see the .war content. Look for `RemoteService.class`. Edit: @Braj comment is the way to go.

Comment: Have you added `gwt-servlet` as dependency in your `pom.xml`?

Comment: I checked the war file, in the lib-folder is no gwt-servlet.jar. I don't have the gwt-servlet in my pom.xml. This is maybe my problem :-)

Comment: Thats it. Simple problem. Thanks for you support :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add the dependency in your `pom.xml`. Replace `${gwtVersion}` in below dependency.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Again do the same step `mvn clean install`

Please have a look at [ClassNotFoundException when deploying GWT-RPC-Applicaton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13567166/classnotfoundexception-when-deploying-gwt-rpc-applicaton-to-jboss-as-7-1-1)